# discord.js Javascript string manipulation

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so i am creating a bot with a kick command and would like to be able to add a reason for said action, i've heard from somewhere that i may have to do string manipulation. currently i have a standalone reason as shown in the code below:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  // Ignore messages that aren't from a guild
  if (!message.guild) return;

  // If the message starts with ".kick"
  if (message.content.startsWith(".kick")) {
    // Assuming we mention someone in the message, this will return the user
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    // If we have a user mentioned
    if (user) {
      // Now we get the member from the user
      const member = message.guild.member(user);
      // If the member is in the server
      if (member) {
        member
          .kick("Optional reason that will display in the audit logs")
          .then(() => {
            // lets the message author know we were able to kick the person
            message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}`);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            // An error happened
            // This is generally due to the bot not being able to kick the member,
            // either due to missing permissions or role hierarchy
            message.reply(
              "I was unable to kick the member (this could be due to missing permissions or role hierarchy"
            );
            // Log the error
            console.error(err);
          });
      } else {
        // The mentioned user isn't in this server
        message.reply("That user isn't in this server!");
      }
      // Otherwise, if no user was mentioned
    } else {
      message.reply("You didn't mention the user to kick!");
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want your full command to look something like

```
.kick @user Being hostile to other members
```

If you want to assume that everything in the command that isn't a mention or the ".kick" command is the reason, then to get the reason from that string, you can do some simple string manipulation to extract the command and mentions from the string, and leave everything else.

Never used the Discord API, but from what I've pieced from the documentation, this should work.

```
let reason = message.content.replaceAll(".kick", "")
message.mentions.forEach((mentionedUser) => reason.replaceAll("@" + mentionedUser.username, "")
// assume everything else left in `reason` is the sentence given by the user as a reason

if (member) {
    member
      .kick(reason)
      .then(() => {
        // lets the message author know we were able to kick the person
        message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}`);
      })
}
```

Comment: quick question where would i implement that

Answer (score 0):

Split `message.content` and slice the first 2 array elements, this will leave you with the elements that make up the reason. Join the remaining elements back to a string.

```
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
const reason = message.content.split(' ').slice(2).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that could help:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(1).split(" "); //1 is the prefix length
const command = args.shift();
//that works as a pretty good command structure
if(command === 'kick') {
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
args.shift();
const reason = args.join(" ");
user.kick(reason);
//really close to Elitezen's answer but you might have a very terrible problem
//if you mention a user inside the reason, depending on the users' id, the bot could kick 
//the user in the reason instead!
}
```

Here's how you can take away that problem (with regex)

```js
const userMention = message.content.match(/<@!?[0-9]+>/);
//you may have to do some more "escapes"
//this works since regex stops at the first one, unless you make it global
var userId = userMention.slice(2, userMention.length-1);
if(userId.startsWith("!")) userId = userId.slice(1);
const user = message.guild.members.cache.get(userId);
args.shift();
args.shift();
user.kick(args.join(" "))
.then(user => message.reply(user.username + " was kicked successfully"))
.catch(err => message.reply("An error occured: " + err.message))
```